# Is there a quick way to see if a commit hash is in a particular tree's history?

Tags: git

Can I compare a commit to a branch and see if there is a diff, or just get a yes / no answer to the question somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a commit is on a branch's history then this list of commits will be empty, otherwise there will be at least one commit (the given commit).

```
git rev-list <branch_id>..<commit_id>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah:

```
git log <commit hash>
```